# Ethers setup provider for mumbai testnet

Tags: contract-deployment, javascript, ethers.js, testnets, polygon

I try to connect to mumbai testnet in javascript. I don't want to use alchemy, infura or something like this, but want to connect drectly. I already have deployed a smart contract to mumbai-testnet.

I try the following:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.URL);
```

where my Url in the .env file is:

```
URL=https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com/
```

everything works so far, I even get access to my wallet using:

```
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(private_key, provider)
```

now I am connecting my smart contract like this:

```
const contract = new ethers.Contract(deployed_contact_address, abi, provider);
```

I think this also works so far, if I use console.log to show the contract, I can see the functions included in smart contract.
But if I want to access the functions like this:

```
var out_min = contract.getAmountOutMin(dict_routers.get("uniswap_v2"), dict_bA.get("MATIC"), dict_tok.get("DAI"), 100);
```

I get an error:

```
node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:233
        var error = new Error(message);
                    ^

Error: network does not support ENS (operation="getResolver", network="maticmum", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.6.8)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\danis\arbitrage_bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:233:21)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\danis\arbitrage_bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:242:20)
    at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (C:\Users\danis\arbitrage_bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:2305:36)
    at step (C:\Users\danis\arbitrage_bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\danis\arbitrage_bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\danis\arbitrage_bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:20:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  reason: 'network does not support ENS',
  code: 'UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION',
  operation: 'getResolver',
  network: 'maticmum'
}
```

Can someone tell me, what is going wrong here? I don't know what to do anymore.
Thank you!

Comment: Without knowing the contract you are calling and what your input looks like, it is very hard to tell. I would guess that one of the addresses has an incorrect format (should be an address, but is a string) and thus is interpreted as ENS

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I check this? How can I change the string to an address?

Answer (score 0):

Your address is coming up as a string.  To try a fix, just paste the address (e.g. "0x12345..." into the field where the variable name is

If that's your issue, its just a javascript issue on reading the env/variable correctly

Comment: I replaced all variable names with the addresses, but it is still not working

Comment: are the addresses in quotes?

Comment: I tried with quotes and without quotes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to the smart contract you have to sign it with a ***signer*** argument..hope it will help.